# Set multiple buttons text in android

Tags: java, android

I wrote a quiz game in android. I want every time that game goes to next question, all buttons texts also update with each string that exists in string.xml. My string.xml file has include `<string>` values like below for every questios:

```
<!-- Second question-->
<string name="secondQ_A1">Oracle</string>
<string name="secondQ_A2">Apple</string>
<string name="secondQ_A3">Sun Microsystems</string> <!-- Right answer -->
<string name="secondQ_A4">IBM</string>
```

And here's the code:

```
private Question[] questions = new Question[] {
            new Question(R.drawable.first, R.string.first_question_text, R.string.firstQ_A2),
            new Question(R.drawable.second, R.string.second_question_text, R.string.secondQ_A3),
            new Question(R.drawable.third, R.string.third_question_text, R.string.thirdQ_A2),
};

private ImageView questionImage;
private TextView questionText;
private Button[] answerButtons;

private int currentQuestion = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_play);

        //Initializing
        initializeFields();

        int textQ = questions[currentQuestion].getResQuestionText();
        questionText.setText(textQ);
        int imageQ = questions[currentQuestion].getResQuestionImg();
        questionImage.setImageResource(imageQ);

        for (Button button : answerButtons) {
            button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                if (currentQuestion + 1 < questions.length) {
                    currentQuestion += 1;
                    updateQuestion();
                }
            });
        }
}

public void updateQuestion() {
        int textQ = questions[currentQuestion].getResQuestionText();
        questionText.setText(textQ);
        int imageQ = questions[currentQuestion].getResQuestionImg();
        questionImage.setImageResource(imageQ);
        List<Integer> firstQ_answers = new LinkedList<>();
        firstQ_answers.add(R.string.firstQ_A1);
        firstQ_answers.add(R.string.firstQ_A2);
        firstQ_answers.add(R.string.firstQ_A3);
        firstQ_answers.add(R.string.firstQ_A4);
        for (int i = 0; i< answerButtons.length; i++) {
            questions[currentQuestion].setOptions(firstQ_answers);
            
        answerButtons[i].setText(questions[currentQuestion].getOptions().get(i));
        }
}
```

And also `Question` class:

```
public class Question {

    private int resQuestionText;
    private int resQuestionImg;
    private int resAnswer;

    public Question(int resQuestionImg, int resQuestionText, int resAnswer) {
        this.resQuestionImg = resQuestionImg;
        this.resQuestionText = resQuestionText;
        this.resAnswer = resAnswer;
    }

    public int getResQuestionText() {
        return resQuestionText;
    }

    public int getResQuestionImg() {
        return resQuestionImg;
    }

    public int getResAnswer() {
        return resAnswer;
    }

}
```

The `updateQuestion()` method just work for question's image and text, but the buttons has no text. I want to update buttons text with that string.xml file values above. Actually I got no idea about it, anyone can guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code , you are not even updating it , so you have to do something like this in your `updateQueation()` method :

```
answerButtons[0].setText(getString(R.string.secondQ_A1));
answerButtons[1].setText(getString(R.string.secondQ_A2));
answerButtons[2].setText(getString(R.string.secondQ_A3));
answerButtons[3].setText(getString(R.string.secondQ_A4));
```

As best practice you should define a global two dimensional array to hold all questions index and its options like :

```
int[][] myOptions ={{allFirstQuestionAnswersResHere},{second},{third},...};
```

And then in updateQuestion() use question number to get the options from your global array like :

```
for(int i=0;i<answerButtons.length();i++){
answerButtons[i].setText(myOptions[questionIndex][i]);
}
```

**Enjoy !**

Comment: There are multiple questions (about 10), I don't think I have to use ```.setText()``` for every question. That's not right

Comment: Updated , check the update . You can't set the button with using setText() mthod , unless you are using databinding , you can wrap this lines in your updateQuestion method and use it every time the question get change .

Comment: I almost did your help, but app got a crash. But I doubt that I did this in right way. Would you be more specific please?

Comment: This should work , can you please edit your post with the error shown in the logcat ?

Comment: Actually I added ```List<String> options;``` in Question class. And also added setter and getter for this field. Then in updateQuestion() I did this: `for (int i = 0; i< answerButtons.length; i++) { answerButtons[i].setText(questions[currentQuestion].getOptions().get(i));}`
Am I wrong?

Comment: So where did you actually set your options list ?

Comment: I changed the `List<String>` to `List<Integer>` then added those string values to this. Check out my post and see the `updateQuestion()` that I edited. This changed worked, but just only for the first question. I mean other string values for rest of the questions won't be set to button's text.

Comment: Hey I updated it again so you can get it .

Comment: I already got it. But as I said it just work for one string value, so what about rest of the questions text?

Comment: I will update it again  , for this case i will give you a simple solution .

Comment: If you would now, I'll be appreciate

Comment: I did , and i made it very easy for you now !

Answer (score 0):

you are using int as a text in your question that's why it cant be set so

```
questionText.setText(" "+textQ);
```

or change int questionText to String questionText.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same by changing your question class like this

```
public class Question {

private int resQuestionText;
private int resQuestionImg;
private int resAnswer[];

public Question(int resQuestionImg, int resQuestionText, int resAnswer[]) {
    this.resQuestionImg = resQuestionImg;
    this.resQuestionText = resQuestionText;
    this.resAnswer = resAnswer;
}

public int getResQuestionText() {
    return resQuestionText;
}

public int getResQuestionImg() {
    return resQuestionImg;
}

public int [] getResAnswer() {
    return resAnswer;
}
```

}

and then in your updateQuestion method

```
 public void updateQuestion() {
  // you can get array of button text for each question like below and can         update your buttons text by iterating through this array

        int buttonTexts[] = questions[currentQuestion].getResAnswer();

        int textQ = questions[currentQuestion].getResQuestionText();
        questionText.setText(textQ);
        int imageQ = questions[currentQuestion].getResQuestionImg();
        questionImage.setImageResource(imageQ);
}
```